# Is swapping a const member undefined behavior? C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics

https://godbolt.org/z/E3ETx8a88

Is this swapping UB? Am I mutating anything? UBSAN does not report anything.

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct MyInt
{
    MyInt(int ii): i(ii) {}
    const int i;
    MyInt& operator=(MyInt&& rh)
    {
        std::swap(const_cast<int&>(i), const_cast<int&>(rh.i));
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyInt i0(0);
    MyInt i2(2);

    i0 = std::move(i2);
    return i0.i;
}
```

Comment: If you have to ask about a `const_cast`, it's a bad idea.

Comment: I don't think there is a ubsan check for modifying `const` objects, but you can use a constant expression evaluation to see that it is UB: https://godbolt.org/z/PM6W9K5T6

Comment: The various *casts* is the programmer telling the compiler "I know this looks bad, but ignore that, and trust me, I know what I'm doing."  The compiler plugs its nose and does what it is told.  In this case, the trust is unfounded.  Lie to the compiler, and the compiler responds with **undefined behavior** (UB).  If you are lucky, UB results in a crash.  If are unlucky, UB appears to work.  You have gotten unlucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an area of c++ evolution.

It's UB in c++17 because of [this restriction on replacing const member objects](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8.3)

However, in later versions, [this restriction is mostly removed.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#8.3). There remains a restriction on complete const objects. For instance you can't do this if `MyInt i0(0);` was `const MyInt i0(0);`

Even though c++20 now allows modification of const sub objects, it's best to avoid `const_cast` and use this to create an assignment ctor. In this case one doesn't need a destructor since it's trivially destructable. Note that one had to use placement new prior to c++20 and that was still UB since const sub objects were not permitted to change previously.

```
constexpr MyInt& operator=(MyInt&& rh)
{
    std::construct_at(&this->i, rh.i);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: That means rewriting const subobjects is possible at all. But can it legally be done with `swap`?

Comment: @Sebastian Good question. While the assignment copy constructor can certainly be written w/o UB which means the `const int` is modifiable w/o UB, whether this casting to allow a swap is legal is questionable. It probably should be based on the basic.life change but that may require further evolution. My preference is use of `construct_at` which can be used. Clunky for move ctor though.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this swapping UB?

Yes, this is UB.

> Am I mutating anything?

You are mutating const objects. That's not allowed.

Comment: UBSAN does not report anything and godbolt exit code is "expected" equal to 2

Comment: @pettitpeon ubsan checks only for a number of common sources of UB, not all of them. That the program behaves as "expected" does not in any way imply that it doesn't have undefined behavior.

Comment: Getting the expected results is no guarantee for defined behaviour. You should declare the variables as non-const and cast them to const. Casting them back later to non-const and modifying them is defined behaviour.

Comment: @pettitpeon `UBSAN does not report anything` UBSAN isn't perfect. `exit code is "expected" equal to 2` Why do you expect the output to equal 2? When behaviour of the program is undefined, you cannot rely on any behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

From [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)

> Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.

so Yes, that is UB.